# Comparing two schemas to find changes

Tags: xml, xsd

I am looking at 20000 line schema and I want to check what has changed in this schema since previous release. I need to figure out what is different in 2 versions of same schema.

Are there any good tools for that? 90% of schema is still the same, but I want some kind of list of changes. Any help is appreciated.

edit => The challenge in comparison is that version 1 of the schema is split into 4 schema (one including another)  and version 2 is one single merged schema.

Comment: I am asking about XML schemas, that's the reason I tagged my question with XSD and XML

Answer (score 1):

[QTAssistant](http://www.paschidev.com) (I am associated with it) has an XML Schema compare built in the XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) module. All you need to do is:

- Create a new XML Schema Refactoring File
- Create a new XML Schema collection. You automatically get a Version 1.0.0 associated with this collection.
- Add your first set of XSD files (one or more, whatever is you consider a version).
- Add a new version (it'll be automatically incremented to 1.1.0)
- Add your other version's files to this.
- Right click on the the one of the versions and invoke the Compare with Version... command
- At the prompt choose **the other** version to compare with.

[image: QTAssistant XSR choose schema version]

- Explore the report. You can export it in Excel, etc.

This is showing comparing two different versions of [ACORD](http://www.acord.org/), 2.21.0 vs. 2.26.0; I've picked them since also one is 1 file, and the other is 4 files.

[image: QTAssistant XML Schema diff]

This is what a report looks like.

[image]

When you click on the source, you can see a graphical representation, side by side (if applicable).

[image]

It may get some time to get used to the Status and Extended status, and in our experience different people may have a different interpretation, since nuances in XSD compare can be multiple. Nonetheless, support is one email away.

Comment: In fact I am working on ACORD schema itself. The information that you provided is very helpful. By any means does your tool provide the ability to slice the schema into a subset? The full Acord schema is huge and we do not need 80% of the stuff in there for our transactions.

Comment: A lucky guess (ACORD was the only example I could think of which matched your scenario). Yes, you could do that very easily - the tool was designed for that. If you wish, contact me directly through the support address on my website and we can take it from there.